# sql nested query with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I was reading some tutorials about group by clause, i faced the following problem and don't know why it was solved like that, the table is as follows:

[image]

the requirement is to select the most expensive product in each category, and the following query was the answer:

```
SELECT 
categoryID, productID, productName, MAX(unitprice)

FROM
products A

WHERE
unitprice = (

SELECT 
        MAX(unitprice)

    FROM
        products B

    WHERE
        B.categoryId = A.categoryID)

GROUP BY categoryID;
```

i don't know why the above query was the answer, why it wasn't just:

```
SELECT 
categoryID, productID, productName, MAX(unitprice)

FROM
products 

GROUP BY categoryID;
```

also, if the first query is the right one, why `MAX` function exists in the outer and inner query, isn't it enough to exist in the inner query?
thanks.

Comment: The second query aggregates over categoryid only, thus the result set does not provide the columns productid and productname.

Comment: the first one does not work in any database i know. are you using mysql by chance?

Comment: Please turn on the strict group by mode in MySQL. Or don't use MySQL if you don't know what you're not the master of SQL, it's dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

The second query will produce an error because it is not possible to have columns in the select clause whitout grouping by them in the Group by clause (unless they are subject to the aggregation).
Therefore you need to first find the highest unit price in each category and then find which product has that uniprice. You can actually accomplish this in many ways. This first query is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

From your picture it looks as others have mentioned that you are using mysql, the MYSQL optimiser doesn't like subqueries very much and it would horrible to run over lots of data, best habit is to use joins where possible (if you look at query plans in postgres, oracle or mssql it will re-write sub-queries as joins 90% of the time)

The second query will run on default mysql as it will group by the missed columns you missed.

Below is an example:

```
SELECT 
A.categoryID, A.productID, A.productName, B.max_unitprice
FROM products A
JOIN (
SELECT 
max(unit price) as max_unitprice, 
categoryId
FROM products
GROUP BY categoryId) B
ON B.categoryId = A.categoryID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'p2'
                   FROM products p2
                   WHERE p2.categoryId = p.categoryId
                   AND p2.unitPrice > p.unitPrice
                  )
```